# Lining my social media icons beside each other?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get my social media icons to line up side by side, but it's not working?
I'm probably just being dense, but my brain is mush today.

HTML

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="icons">
             <img src="assets/webicon-facebook.png" alt="facebook link"> 
             <img src="assets/webicon-googleplus.png" alt="google plus link">
 </div>
 </div>
```

I had tried to do display and do it inline, but that didn't work. I don't know if the Foundation grid is messing with it?

Comment: It is impossible to say without seeing a demo. Please create a jsfiddle or link to live site. At the very least, also include the CSS used

Comment: Do you have any CSS associated with your example above? If so, could you please post it?

Comment: Also, you have 4 open `<div>` tags but only two of those are closed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/missxcurious/fjq4ntgj/

There are images missing, but the one's in the center are the one's that are my social media icons. I also closed the div tags.

Comment: @missxcurious Do you have a CSS rule for .panel img { } somewhere? If I go into developer tools in Chrome for your images and remove "display: block" it works as you seem to intend.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I cannot do that because I've other images on other pages. Can I identify it to the panel class, icons class, and label it important?...*ponders*

Comment: @missxcurious Have you tried setting up a class on those 3 specific images and isolating them that way? At least then you can create a separate CSS rule for those 3 specific images and it won't affect any others. If no changes present themselves, try putting !important at the end of every property given inside your new rule.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I actually just did that. I appreciate the assistance walking through that. Now, it's putting them inline but I want them centered on the page. If I do margins auto, it puts them vertical again. Any tips?

Comment: @missxcurious Refer to this jsfiddle. I believe it will provide you with your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/6PaXB/

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed them to display:block they're no longer being displayed inline. You have two options: either display them inline-block or float them.

Option 1:

```
.panel img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: left;
}
```

Option 2:

```
.panel img {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I removed the display elements completely, and they're side by side now. But I cannot get them to center, as a whole, on the bottom of the page. If I try either of those methods, they end up stacked in the center but one on top of the other.

Comment: if you display:inline-block, you can set the parent div to text-align:center;

Comment: in your case, your .icons class you would set text-algin:center; if you used my option 2

Comment: It wasn't working. I'm so irritated at this point, I'm leaving them where they are and coming back to this issue tomorrow. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can use either:

Inline Lists: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/inline_lists.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul class="inline-list">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/webicon-facebook.png" alt="facebook link"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/webicon-googleplus.png" alt="google plus link"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Block Grid: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns>
            <div class="panel">
                <ul class="small-block-grid-2">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/webicon-facebook.png" alt="facebook link"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/webicon-googleplus.png" alt="google plus link"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope that helps.